# Hibernate criteria projection JList

Tags: hibernate, jlist, projection, hibernate-criteria

I have a gui with a JList which is supposed to contain all the fields and values ​​categories1 categories2 of a personality without duplicates and sorted alphabetically.

To do this, I use a method with criteria and projection

```
public List<TPersonalities> findAllCategories(){
    getSession().beginTransaction();
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(TPersonalities.class);
    ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("category1")).add(Projections.property("category2"));
    criteria.setProjection(projList);
    criteria.addOrder( Property.forName("category1").asc()).addOrder( Property.forName("category2").asc());
    return criteria.list();
}
```

And here is the method in PersonalitiesController sense display the result of findAllCategorie():

```
public void setJListForCategories(List<TPersonalities> personalitiesListCat, JList listCategories){
       DefaultListModel modelList = new DefaultListModel();
       for(int i = 0; i < personalitiesListCat.size(); i++){
            modelList.addElement(personalitiesListCat.get(i));
       }

        listCategories.setModel(modelList);
        setListNames(listCategories);
}
```

the problem is that when I run the application to test it shows me the addresses of objects, style: [Ljava.lang.Object;@4a9c1114 ...
What can I do to solve this problem???

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `toString()` method to `TPersonalities` such as:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return parameterOfTPersonalities;
}
```

Comment: Hello
Thank you for your reply .... I forgot to mention that I had already override toString .... and that nothing change ...
Here's the code:

Comment: '@Override
 public String toString() {
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  sb.append(this.nameKnow).append(", ").append(this.name)
  .append(", ").append(this.firstname).append(", ").append(this.dateDetails)
  .append(", ").append(this.category1).append(", ").append(this.category2).append(", ")
  .append(this.dateDetails).append(", ").append(this.image).append(", ")
  .append(this.wikipediaLink).append(", ").append(this.websiteLink).append(", ")
  .append(this.description);
  return sb.toString();
 }'

Answer (score 0):

Re..Now I try to retrieve all is concerne category2 on my findAllCategories() and there is no problem but now I have only category1 and no category2 value and there is some duplication...

here is the code of:

```
public List<TPersonalities> findAllCategories(){
    getSession().beginTransaction();
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(TPersonalities.class);
    ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("category1"));//.add(Projections.property("category2"));

    criteria.setProjection(projList);
    criteria.addOrder( Property.forName("category1").asc());//.addOrder( Property.forName("category2").asc());
    return criteria.list();
}
```